# How to remove index.php from htaccess when redirect 301 - Codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-3

I have a problem in Codeigniter when the url type is:

```
example.gov.ar/news (without www and .gov)
```

I need it to redirect to:

```
www.example.gob.ar/news (with www and .gob)
```

But it redirect

```
www.example.gob.ar/index.php/news
```

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#.gov.ar to .gob.ar
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.gov.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.gov.ar$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.gob.ar/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: my config file have $config['index_page'] = '';

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the order of your rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

#non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#.gov.ar to .gob.ar
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.gov.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.gov.ar$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.gob.ar/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect to index.php internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

An external redirect triggered by .htaccess is re-evaluated against all rules, therefore order is important.

In the changed order, the external redirects happen first, so just the final URL is matched against the third RewriteRule, which then does not become visible externally.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Genius!!